# Failed to Parse WSDL:External schema import not supported

Tags: webservices, xml, wsdl, wsdl2apex

While parsing the WSDL in throws an error as External schema import not supported

Error: Failed to parse wsdl: Found schema import from location http://crcind.com/csp/samples/SOAP.ByNameDataSet.cls?XSD. External schema import not supported

Xml file is

```
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:s0="http://tempuri.org" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org">
    <types>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org">
    <s:import namespace="http://tempuri.org/ByNameDataSet" schemaLocation="http://crcind.com/csp/samples/SOAP.ByNameDataSet.cls?XSD"/>
    <s:import namespace="http://tempuri.org/QueryByName_DataSet" schemaLocation="http://crcind.com/csp/samples/SOAP.Demo.QueryByName.DS.cls?XSD"/>
    <s:element name="AddInteger">
    <s:complexType>
    <s:sequence>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" name="Arg1" type="s:long"/>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" name="Arg2" type="s:long"/>
    </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
    </s:element>
    <s:element name="AddIntegerResponse">
    <s:complexType>
    <s:sequence>
    <s:element name="AddIntegerResult" type="s:long"/>
    </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
    </s:element>
    <s:element name="DivideInteger">
    <s:complexType>
    <s:sequence>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" name="Arg1" type="s:long"/>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" name="Arg2" type="s:long"/>
    </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
    </s:element>
    <s:element name="DivideIntegerResponse">
    <s:complexType>
    <s:sequence>
    <s:element name="DivideIntegerResult" type="s:long"/>
    </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
    </s:element>
    <s:element name="FindPerson">
    <s:complexType>
    <s:sequence>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" name="id" type="s:string"/>
    </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
    </s:element>
    <s:element name="FindPersonResponse">
    <s:complexType>
    <s:sequence>
    <s:element name="FindPersonResult" type="s0:Person"/>
    </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
    </s:element>
    <s:complexType name="Employee">
    <s:complexContent>
    <s:extension base="s0:Person">
    <s:sequence>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" name="Title">
    <s:simpleType>
    <s:restriction base="s:string">
    <s:maxLength value="50"/>
    </s:restriction>
    </s:simpleType>
    </s:element>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" name="Salary">
    <s:simpleType>
    <s:restriction base="s:long">
    <s:maxInclusive value="100000"/>
    <s:minInclusive value="0"/>
    </s:restriction>
    </s:simpleType>
    </s:element>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" name="Notes" type="s:string"/>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" name="Picture" type="s:base64Binary"/>
    </s:sequence>
    </s:extension>
    </s:complexContent>
    </s:complexType>
    <s:complexType name="Person">
    <s:sequence>
    <s:element name="Name" type="s:string"/>
    <s:element name="SSN" type="s:string"/>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" name="DOB" type="s:date"/>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" name="Home" type="s0:Address"/>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" name="Office" type="s0:Address"/>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" name="Spouse" type="s0:Person"/>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" name="FavoriteColors" type="s0:ArrayOfFavoriteColorsItemString"/>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" name="Age" type="s:long"/>
    </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
    <s:complexType name="Address">
    <s:sequence>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" name="Street">
    <s:simpleType>
    <s:restriction base="s:string">
    <s:maxLength value="80"/>
    </s:restriction>
    </s:simpleType>
    </s:element>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" name="City">
    <s:simpleType>
    <s:restriction base="s:string">
    <s:maxLength value="80"/>
    </s:restriction>
    </s:simpleType>
    </s:element>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" name="State">
    <s:simpleType>
    <s:restriction base="s:string">
    <s:maxLength value="2"/>
    </s:restriction>
    </s:simpleType>
    </s:element>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" name="Zip">
    <s:simpleType>
    <s:restriction base="s:string">
    <s:maxLength value="5"/>
    </s:restriction>
    </s:simpleType>
    </s:element>
    </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
    <s:complexType name="ArrayOfFavoriteColorsItemString">
    <s:sequence>
    <s:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="FavoriteColorsItem" nillable="true" type="s:string"/>
    </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
    <s:element name="GetByName">
    <s:complexType>
    <s:sequence>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" name="name" type="s:string"/>
    </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
    </s:element>
    <s:element name="GetByNameResponse">
    <s:complexType>
    <s:sequence>
    <s:element name="GetByNameResult" type="s0:DataSet"/>
    </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
    </s:element>
    <s:complexType name="DataSet">
    <s:sequence>
    <s:element ref="s:schema"/>
    <s:any/>
    </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
    <s:element name="GetDataSetByName">
    <s:complexType>
    <s:sequence>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" name="name" type="s:string"/>
    </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
    </s:element>
    <s:element name="GetDataSetByNameResponse">
    <s:complexType>
    <s:sequence>
    <s:element name="GetDataSetByNameResult" type="s0:ByNameDataSet"/>
    </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
    </s:element>
    <s:complexType name="ByNameDataSet">
    <s:sequence>
    <s:any namespace="http://tempuri.org/ByNameDataSet"/>
    </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
    <s:element name="GetListByName">
    <s:complexType>
    <s:sequence>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" name="name" type="s:string"/>
    </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
    </s:element>
    <s:element name="GetListByNameResponse">
    <s:complexType>
    <s:sequence>
    <s:element name="GetListByNameResult" type="s0:ArrayOfPersonIdentificationPersonIdentification"/>
    </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
    </s:element>
    <s:complexType name="ArrayOfPersonIdentificationPersonIdentification">
    <s:sequence>
    <s:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="PersonIdentification" nillable="true" type="s0:PersonIdentification"/>
    </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
    <s:complexType name="PersonIdentification">
    <s:sequence>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" name="ID" type="s:string"/>
    <s:element name="Name" type="s:string"/>
    <s:element name="SSN" type="s:string"/>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" name="DOB" type="s:date"/>
    </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
    <s:element name="LookupCity">
    <s:complexType>
    <s:sequence>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" name="zip" type="s:string"/>
    </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
    </s:element>
    <s:element name="LookupCityResponse">
    <s:complexType>
    <s:sequence>
    <s:element name="LookupCityResult" type="s0:Address"/>
    </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
    </s:element>
    <s:element name="Mission">
    <s:complexType>
    <s:sequence/>
    </s:complexType>
    </s:element>
    <s:element name="MissionResponse">
    <s:complexType>
    <s:sequence>
    <s:element name="MissionResult" type="s:string"/>
    </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
    </s:element>
    <s:element name="QueryByName">
    <s:complexType>
    <s:sequence>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" name="name" type="s:string"/>
    </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
    </s:element>
    <s:element name="QueryByNameResponse">
    <s:complexType>
    <s:sequence>
    <s:element name="QueryByNameResult" type="s0:QueryByName_DataSet"/>
    </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
    </s:element>
    <s:complexType name="QueryByName_DataSet">
    <s:sequence>
    <s:any namespace="http://tempuri.org/QueryByName_DataSet"/>
    </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
     <schema></schema>
    </s:schema>
    </types>
    <message name="AddIntegerSoapIn">
    <part name="parameters" element="s0:AddInteger"/>
    </message>
    <message name="AddIntegerSoapOut">
    <part name="parameters" element="s0:AddIntegerResponse"/>
    </message>
    <message name="DivideIntegerSoapIn">
    <part name="parameters" element="s0:DivideInteger"/>
    </message>
    <message name="DivideIntegerSoapOut">
    <part name="parameters" element="s0:DivideIntegerResponse"/>
    </message>
    <message name="FindPersonSoapIn">
    <part name="parameters" element="s0:FindPerson"/>
    </message>
    <message name="FindPersonSoapOut">
    <part name="parameters" element="s0:FindPersonResponse"/>
    </message>
    <message name="GetByNameSoapIn">
    <part name="parameters" element="s0:GetByName"/>
    </message>
    <message name="GetByNameSoapOut">
    <part name="parameters" element="s0:GetByNameResponse"/>
    </message>
    <message name="GetDataSetByNameSoapIn">
    <part name="parameters" element="s0:GetDataSetByName"/>
    </message>
    <message name="GetDataSetByNameSoapOut">
    <part name="parameters" element="s0:GetDataSetByNameResponse"/>
    </message>
    <message name="GetListByNameSoapIn">
    <part name="parameters" element="s0:GetListByName"/>
    </message>
    <message name="GetListByNameSoapOut">
    <part name="parameters" element="s0:GetListByNameResponse"/>
    </message>
    <message name="LookupCitySoapIn">
    <part name="parameters" element="s0:LookupCity"/>
    </message>
    <message name="LookupCitySoapOut">
    <part name="parameters" element="s0:LookupCityResponse"/>
    </message>
    <message name="MissionSoapIn">
    <part name="parameters" element="s0:Mission"/>
    </message>
    <message name="MissionSoapOut">
    <part name="parameters" element="s0:MissionResponse"/>
    </message>
    <message name="QueryByNameSoapIn">
    <part name="parameters" element="s0:QueryByName"/>
    </message>
    <message name="QueryByNameSoapOut">
    <part name="parameters" element="s0:QueryByNameResponse"/>
    </message>
    <portType name="SOAPDemoSoap">
    <operation name="AddInteger">
    <input message="s0:AddIntegerSoapIn"/>
    <output message="s0:AddIntegerSoapOut"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="DivideInteger">
    <input message="s0:DivideIntegerSoapIn"/>
    <output message="s0:DivideIntegerSoapOut"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="FindPerson">
    <input message="s0:FindPersonSoapIn"/>
    <output message="s0:FindPersonSoapOut"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="GetByName">
    <input message="s0:GetByNameSoapIn"/>
    <output message="s0:GetByNameSoapOut"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="GetDataSetByName">
    <input message="s0:GetDataSetByNameSoapIn"/>
    <output message="s0:GetDataSetByNameSoapOut"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="GetListByName">
    <input message="s0:GetListByNameSoapIn"/>
    <output message="s0:GetListByNameSoapOut"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="LookupCity">
    <input message="s0:LookupCitySoapIn"/>
    <output message="s0:LookupCitySoapOut"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="Mission">
    <input message="s0:MissionSoapIn"/>
    <output message="s0:MissionSoapOut"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="QueryByName">
    <input message="s0:QueryByNameSoapIn"/>
    <output message="s0:QueryByNameSoapOut"/>
    </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="SOAPDemoSoap" type="s0:SOAPDemoSoap">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
    <operation name="AddInteger">
    <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/SOAP.Demo.AddInteger" style="document"/>
    <input>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </input>
    <output>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="DivideInteger">
    <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/SOAP.Demo.DivideInteger" style="document"/>
    <input>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </input>
    <output>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="FindPerson">
    <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/SOAP.Demo.FindPerson" style="document"/>
    <input>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </input>
    <output>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="GetByName">
    <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/SOAP.Demo.GetByName" style="document"/>
    <input>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </input>
    <output>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="GetDataSetByName">
    <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/SOAP.Demo.GetDataSetByName" style="document"/>
    <input>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </input>
    <output>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="GetListByName">
    <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/SOAP.Demo.GetListByName" style="document"/>
    <input>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </input>
    <output>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="LookupCity">
    <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/SOAP.Demo.LookupCity" style="document"/>
    <input>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </input>
    <output>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="Mission">
    <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/SOAP.Demo.Mission" style="document"/>
    <input>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </input>
    <output>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="QueryByName">
    <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/SOAP.Demo.QueryByName" style="document"/>
    <input>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </input>
    <output>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </output>
    </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="SOAPDemo">
    <port name="SOAPDemoSoap" binding="s0:SOAPDemoSoap">
    <soap:address location="http://crcind.com/csp/samples/SOAP.Demo.cls"/>
    </port>
    </service>
    </definitions>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you can't use s:import in a WSDL in the GUI tool. You might consider [wsdl2apex](https://github.com/forcedotcom/WSDL2Apex), or you can try to manually paste the external links into the XML file, although I've found this challenging to do in the past for any non-trivial service.